# Telerik RadTabStrip doesn't render correctly when loaded via AJAX

Tags: asp.net-ajax, telerik

I'm loading a user control dynamically and displaying it using a RadAjaxPanel. The problem is that my RadTabStrip doesn't render correctly. The skin hasn't been applied and I only see part of the text. If I do a complete refresh of the page then it displays perfectly fine and from that point on it will render correctly even if I load it with AJAX again (until I open up a new browser window and start again).

This symptom is also evident with the RadDatePicker (skin not rendering correctly on initial AJAX load).

Any help will be much appreciated!

Dave.

P.S. I should point out that I'm using this line of code to force the RadAjaxPanel to refresh and it's only then that the problem is experienced:

```
pnlAjax.ResponseScripts.Add(String.Format("$find('{0}').ajaxRequest();", pnlAjax.ClientID));
```

Comment: I should also point out that if I use an asp:UpdatePanel, the tabstrip renders fine. However the UpdatePanel causes me other problems such as this error coming up very frequently; "Could not find UpdatePanel with ID 'ctl00_CampaignBrowse_ctl00_UpdatePanel1'. If it is being updated dynamically then it must be inside another UpdatePanel."

Answer (score 1):

If setting `EnableAjaxSkinRendering` to `true` does not help you can try manually including the required CSS files in the `<head>` tag of your page:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Skins/TabStrip.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Skins/Default/TabStrip.Default.css" />
```

Comment: Hi Korchev, thanks for your response. Both very good ideas but I already tried the EnableAjaxSkinRendering as well as the stylesheet links in both the MasterPage and the UserControl in question. It's just not picking up the style at all :( Any other ideas?

Comment: Hm. This is very strange indeed. Manually registering the CSS should have helped. I suggest you check for any JavaScript errors or failing HTTP requests (using FireBug or Fiddler). If neither of this helps I recommend you open a support ticket so we can troubleshoot the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Haven´t used the RadAjax-stuff but using jquery ($.ajax) I got it working just by setting RegisterWithScriptManager="false". Maybe helps someone...

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem with runtime load of Telerik controls on ajax request and this was fixed after I enabled ajax skin rendering (saw how to do that from [this demo](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/ajax/examples/common/showingwebcontrols/defaultcs.aspx)).

Dick

Comment: Hi Dick, thanks for you suggestion. I've tried this and it hasn't helped.